# Infinite loop in useEffect after an API mock in Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-test-renderer

Seeing some weird things within the component that I am currently working on. So, I am having a server side paginated table, On every API call I am pushing the new records to the existing array. I am using [fetchBaseQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery) to make an API call.

##### Code to achieve it

```
let response = useGetQuery(request); // This hook will perform the API call
const records =
    response.data?.records;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (records) {
      setTableRecords((prevState: any) => [
        ...prevState,
        ...records,
      ]);
    }
  }, [records]);
```

##### Test case for this

```
jest.mock("../endpoints", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../endpoints"),
  useGetQuery: () => ({
    isSuccess: true,
    data: {
      message: "Success",
      records: [], // It gets into infinte loop if I provide this key while mocking
    },
  }),
}));

test("should mount", () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<SomeComponent/>);
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

As, per my understanding if we use array as a dependency in the `useEffect` hook, it might lead to an infinite loop as React uses shallow comparison to check if the dependency’s reference has changed. To fix this, I tried using `useRef` hook, but that doesn't work as per my use case as useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes.

I then tried by making the `response.data` object as a dependency to the useEffect hook, but as per the shallow comparison it is also leading to the infinite loop, so I was then trying to fix it with `useMemo` hook but got no luck as if I pass the dependency as the object it was again leading to the same problem & passing no dependency doesn't work for me.

Is there any other way that I can handle this situation better?

Comment: Why not check the length of the array in the dependecy? So whenever the length changes the useEffect runs? `[records.length]` ?

Comment: @LoXatoR the array length will be constant for the maximum of the cases, so it won't work for them

Comment: useGetQuery its a custom hook rigth? can u sow us how its look like?

Comment: I have updated it within the question

Comment: I have never use fetchBaseQuery but if you save the records in a sate you can use [records] so it will re execute when the records change.

Comment: Yeah, but I have nothing to do with records, I need to push the records to a currently existing array as soon as they are available, and that's why I have used useEffect instead of useState

Comment: I mean to use both, 'useState' for the response or the record, and 'useEffect' with the state as second param, so when you update the state with 'useGetQuery' the state changes, and the 'useEffect' will execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stringify the Array that you are passing in the dependency array if the array is not too large.

```
let response = useGetQuery(request); // This hook will perform the API call
const records =
    response.data?.records;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (records) {
      setTableRecords((prevState: any) => [
        ...prevState,
        ...records,
      ]);
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(records)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the useEffect hook, but instead of passing the api response as an array, I use some parameter, for example if I call an api to get images based on a category, I will only call the api when the category changes:

```js
   const [state, setState] = useState({
      loading: true,
      data: [],
   });

   useEffect(() => {
       myApiMethod(category).then((gifs) => {
          setState({
             loading: false,
             data: gifs,
          });
       });
   }, [category]);
```

Comment: in my case I am unable to do this, because we are making the API call using a hook, and per the rule of hooks, we can't call one hook inside another.

Comment: I didnt know that rule, its a react rule or its yours?

Comment: It's mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) nothing created by me, sorry, actually, as per my use case I am not able to call it inside hook, so I always remembers that I am not able to do that.

Comment: Have you tried to use [request] instead of [records] as second param of useEffect? so, the component will only execute again if the request change

Comment: Will it re-execute once I got a response from the API?

Comment: I dont think so, because the request its the same. Thats why i use the gif api example

Comment: Yeah, so it won't work as expected if I use [request]

Comment: Why not? This will avoid the infinite loop

Comment: Yeah, but in that case the useEffect won't execute when the API response is received,  which is an initial requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating original code, We need to ensure that our mock for **useGetQuery** is correctly set up to return a stable value in our test code.

```
jest.mock("../endpoints");
const useGetQueryMock = useGetQuery as jest.MockedFunction<
  typeof useGetQuery>;

test("should mount", () => {
  useGetQueryMock.mockReturnValue({
    {
    isSuccess: true,
    data: {
      message: "Success",
      records: [],
      },
    }
  });
  const component = renderer.create(<SomeComponent/>);
  const tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: But if we are experiencing this with test cases, can't there be any use case that it might occur within the original code as well?

Comment: @DikshaGoyal I cannot see any scenario in the original code where it might occur. This useEffect is executed solely when there is a change in the returned value from getAPI. The issue with the test code arises from providing a fresh value during each render, which results in an endless loop.